# Account Login Action using Java

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection

I've been working on a simulate login action to a website using java.

Firstly I post my login information,
then I get the cookies(sessionID),
At last I get the content of the website with the cookie I've got.

Now I've successfully got the cookie, but having a problem using it. The cookie contains 3 fields, sessionID, path and domain.

```
mainURL = new URL("login url");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) mainURL.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionID);
connection.getInputStream();
```

I'm sure the URL I'm using matches the cookie.domain and cookie.path.

I've already try using both cookie and sessionID, and using method 
    connection.connect();
and
    connection.getInputStream();
none of them worked.

Hope somebody teach me how to fix this. Thanks very much.

Edit: Thanks for your answer. But rather knowing how to accomplish the desire function, I prefer knowing what's wrong about my method while others using the alike method could success.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may consider using [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) or [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) , which provide rich set of feature than plain `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But rather knowing how to accomplish the desire function, I prefer knowing what's wrong about my method while others using the alike method could success.